# Find command for an FTP database in Python

Tags: python, database, find

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

The only solutions I've seen to my problem have all been `subprocess`. However, all of the `subprocess` methods only search in the local device, my computer. Is there a way to search for a directory or file within other directories in an database with only FTP privileges?

I'm sorry I can't really develop an MWE because I would actually need to ftp into the database.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html

Comment: Have you read [ask]?